# Django: Issue displaying updates for a MultipleChoiceField, template keeps displaying initial values

Tags: django

First post, apologies in advance for errors.

My problem:
I initialize my model fields from a proprietary db. These fields are displayed correctly in my template upon first display (I can see the html reflects the values in my proprietary db). I then change the initial selection options (for the MultiSelectField) in my template, and save these changed options to the Django db (verified its saved via the admin function) via post overloading in my views. My success_url is setup in urls.py to redisplay the same view. I have overloaded get_context_data in views to load the form data from the Django database, and to update context data with this loaded data, the idea being that when the templates redisplays (when selecting the submit_button), my html form should now displays the from data loaded from the Django db (not the initial values). What's happening, though, is that the initial values seems to be displayed, as opposed to the changed values I have loaded from the Django db. I would really appreciate help wrt understanding why the template displays values other than what I have loaded from the Django db. The form value that I update in my context before returning it in views.py is not what is displayed in the template.

my models.py:

```
class LiquidAssetModel(models.Model):
   #Get my initial values from an external db
   unq_assets = Jnance_base_data_main.get_unq_assets()
   init_values = Jnance_base_data_main.get_liq_indexes()
   liq_dates = Jnance_base_data_main.get_dates()

   #initialize my fields
   liquid_choices = MultiSelectField(choices = unq_assets, default = init_values)
   from_date = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=liq_dates, default=liq_dates[0][0])
   to_date = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=liq_dates, default=liq_dates[0][0])

   def __str__(self):
      return self.from_date
```

My froms.py:

```
class LiquidAssetsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   # specify the name of model to use
   class Meta:
      model = LiquidAssetModel
      fields = "__all__"
```

My post overload from views.py

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    #form = forms.LiquidAssetsForm(request.POST)

    #form.is_valid goes to the LiquidAssetsForm class and clean(self) overload to check whether the submitted data is fine
    if form.is_valid():
        liquid_indexes = form.cleaned_data.get('liquid_choices')
        from_index = form.cleaned_data.get('from_date')
        to_index = form.cleaned_data.get('to_date')

        #cleare the database
        all_forms = LiquidAssetModel.objects.all()
        all_forms.delete()

        form.save(commit=False)
        form.save(commit=True)

        #save our liquid asset choices to db
        Jnance_base_data_main.put_liq(liquid_indexes)

        #make sure the db is set up, copy the excel files, and then load them into the db
        Jnance_base_data_main.gen_liq_graph(liquid_indexes, int(from_index), int(to_index))

        return self.form_valid(form, **kwargs)

    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)
```

my get_context_data overload from views.py:

```
 class LiquidView(FormView):
    template_name = 'liquid_chart.html'
    form_class = forms.LiquidAssetsForm
    success_url ="/thanksLiquid/"
    liq_file_name = ''

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(LiquidView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

       #build the string to search for a date_NAV file
       search_str = settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/Jnance_Mainapp/images/date_liq*'
       search_str = search_str.replace('\\', '/')

       #search for a file
       the_files = glob.glob(search_str)

       #split the string and only use the part after 'static/', since we will use the static template tag in the html
       if the_files:
          #just use the very first file we found in the list
          self.liq_file_name = the_files[0].split('static/')[1]
          self.liq_file_name = self.liq_file_name.replace('\\', '/')
       else:
          print("Jnance_Mainapp: views LiquidView no liquid chart found to display")

       #update our context with the file name
       context.update({'liquid_file_name': self.liq_file_name})

       form_class = self.get_form_class()
       form = self.get_form(form_class)
       the_obj = LiquidAssetModel.objects.all()

       if len(the_obj) == 0:
          #no forms saved yet
          pass
       else:
          form.liquid_choices = the_obj.values('liquid_choices')[0]
          form.from_date = the_obj.values('from_date')[0]
          form.to_date = the_obj.values('to_date')[0]

       print (form.liquid_choices)

       context.update({'form': form})

       return context
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('NAV_Charts/', views.NAVView.as_view(), name='NAV_Charts'),
path('Asset_Charts/', views.AssetView.as_view(), name='Asset_Charts'),
path('Liquid_Charts/', views.LiquidView.as_view(), name='Liquid_Charts'),
path('Sum_Charts/', views.SumView.as_view(), name='Sum_Charts'),
path('Base_Load/', views.BaseLoadView.as_view(), name='Base_Load'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name= 'admin'),
path('thanksNAV/', views.NAVView.as_view()),
path('thanksAsset/', views.AssetView.as_view()),
path('thanksLiquid/', views.LiquidView.as_view()),
path('thanksBaseLoadForm/', views.BaseLoadView.as_view()),
path('Jnance_Mainapp/', include('Jnance_Mainapp.urls', namespace='Jnance_Mainapp')),]
```

my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  {% block body_block %}
  <h1 class="text-center display-1" Bootstrap heading (2.5rem = 40px)>Jnance Liquid Assets Chart Generation</h1>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center align-left">
          <img class="img-fluid mb-1" src="{% static liquid_file_name %}" alt="Unable to load chart!"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-left align-left">
          {{ form.from_date|as_crispy_field }}
          <br>
          {{ form.to_date|as_crispy_field }}
          <br>
          <br>
          <input name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Generate" id="update_button"  
                  class="btn btn-success" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-left align-left">
            {{ form.liquid_choices|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </table>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the initial values to whatever the first object is that gets returned in `the_obj = LiquidAssetModel.objects.all()` when you set them with `the_obj.values('liquid_choices')[0]`

Comment: Yes. In my post overload, I delete all previous forms stored in db, and save latest. Only interested in the latest form. Thus, when get_context_data gets accessed, and I load the_obj, there is only 1 object(the latest) in the database, and its values are what I want to display. But in the html {{ form.liquid_choices|as_crispy_field }}, what gets displayed in the template is not what I saved via context.update({'form': form}). It looks like {{ form.liquid_choices|as_crispy_field }} displayes the init_values of the first form stored, as opposed to displaying the values of the current form.

Comment: @Willie To change the initial values after you've created your from instance, you need to use `form.fields["liquid_choices"].initial = the_obj.values('liquid_choices')[0]` Try that.

Comment: having tried form.fields["liquid_choices"].initial = the_obj.values('liquid_choices')[0], {{ form.liquid_choices|as_crispy_field }} now displays fields with no initial values. Adding form.fields["liquid_choices"] = the_obj.values('liquid_choices')[0] right after form.fields["liquid_choices"].initial = the_obj.values('liquid_choices')[0] causes a error "'dict' object has no attribute 'initial'". It almost looks like a memory error